# VUE: Selecting an Input after showing it via v-if

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <button class="button is-primary" @click="showMyTF" ref="mybtn">
    Show my Textfield: 
  </button>
  <input class="input" type="text" value="My textfield value" 
  class="formfield" v-if="showTextField" ref="mytf"/>
</div>
```

And the Vue-Code:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    showTextField: false
  },
  methods: {
    showMyTF() {
        this.showTextField = true;

      this.$refs.mybtn.innerText = "There you have it";
      this.$refs.mytf.select();
    }
  }
})
```

I made a JSFiddle example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Pintiboy/Lkec1n5g/

My question here:
Is it possible to select the text of the textfield right after it gets shown (by clicking the button). It does work after it's there (click the button a second time) but I want it to get selected right after it appers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `this.$nextTick`

```
showMyTF() {
  this.showTextField = true;

  this.$refs.mybtn.innerText = "There you have it";

  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.mytf.select();
  })

}
```

Demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/msg74qw1/1/)

Comment: Wow, never heard of that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could also have two separate event triggers, an @mousedown and @click to call separate functions.

```
<button class="button is-primary" @mousedown="showMyTF" @click="selct" ref="mybtn">
    {{buttonText}}
</button>
<input class="input" type="text" value="My textfield value" class="formfield" v-if="showTextField" ref="mytf"/>
```

and in your script:

```
data: () => ({
    showTextField: false
  }),
  computed: {
    buttonText() {
      if(this.showTextField === false) {
        return 'Show my Textfield:'
      } else {
        return 'There you go'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showMyTF() {
      this.showTextField = true;
    },
    selct() {
      this.$refs.mytf.select();
    }
  },
```